# Thunderbird not being scaled properly on Retina display when an external display is also connected

Tags: display, resolution, firefox

If I use Thunderbird with only the Retina screen of my MBP it's fine. However, if I connect my MBP to an external display with normal resolution, then Thunderbird won't scale properly according to Retina resolution if I move the app back onto the Retina screen, resulting in the fonts being extremely small. I'm not sure if this is an ubiquitous occurrence only happening in my case. If no, there might have already been a solution to it?

Comment: I observe almost the same issue with Thunderbird 45. Starting it on the Retina display the window content is displayed fine. Moving it to the external screen the window content is scaled by 1/4, moving it back it's fine again. Starting TB on the external monitor the window content is displayed fine. Moving it to the Retina display the window content is scaled by 4 and no longer fits into the window frame. However, this problem does not seem to be plugin-related since starting in safe-mode doesn't help. Resizing the window with ill-scaled content temporarily works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK it seems to have been caused by a plugin called [Theme Font & Size Changer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/theme-font-size-changer/?src=search). After I removed this plugin, Thunderbird renders properly.